# Flutter: filterChips don't work anymore when selected by default

Tags: flutter

I want some filterChips checked by default in my genre list.
This is what I have so far:

```
class Filters extends StatefulWidget {
    final List selected;
    Filters({Key? key, required this.selected}) : super(key: key);

    @override
    _FiltersState createState() => _FiltersState();
}


class _FiltersState extends State<Filters> {

    Future<Map> getData() async {
        Tmdb instance = Tmdb();
        var data = await instance.getGenres();

        // Check for error.
        if (instance.error.isNotEmpty) {
            data = {'error': instance.error['message'], 'statusCode': instance.error['statusCode']};
        }

        return data;
    }

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {

   ...

                              child = Column(
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                      Padding(
                                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left:8.0),
                                          child: Align(
                                              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                              child: Container(
                                                  child: Wrap(
                                                      spacing: 5.0,
                                                      runSpacing: 3.0,
                                                      children: <Widget>[
                                                          for (var i = 0; i < data['genres'].length; i++) ...[
                                                              filterChipWidget(
                                                                  chipName: data['genres'][i]['name'],
                                                                  chipId: data['genres'][i]['id'],
                                                                  isChecked: widget.selected.contains(data['genres'][i]['id']),
                                                                  // Listen for the onSelected callback.
                                                                  onSelected:  (isChecked, genreId) {
                                                                      // Store the selected genre id
                                                                      if (isChecked) {
                                                                          if (!selectedItems.contains(genreId)) {
                                                                              selectedItems.add(genreId);
                                                                          }
                                                                      }
                                                                      // Remove the selected genre id
                                                                      else {
                                                                          if (selectedItems.contains(genreId)) {
                                                                              selectedItems.remove(genreId);
                                                                          }
                                                                      }
                                                                  }
                                                              ),
                                                          ]
                                                      ],
                                                  )
                                              ),
                                          ),
                                      ),

   ...


   }
}

class filterChipWidget extends StatefulWidget {
    final String chipName;
    final int chipId;
    final bool isChecked;
    Function(bool, int) onSelected;

    filterChipWidget({Key? key, required this.chipName, required this.chipId, required this.isChecked, required this.onSelected}) : super(key: key);

    @override
    _filterChipWidgetState createState() => _filterChipWidgetState();
}

class _filterChipWidgetState extends State<filterChipWidget> {
    var _isSelected = false;

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        _isSelected = widget.isChecked ? true : false;
        return FilterChip(
            label: Text(widget.chipName),
            labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Color(0xff6200ee),fontSize: 16.0,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            selected: _isSelected,
            shape:RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                  30.0),),
            backgroundColor: Color(0xffededed),
            onSelected: (isSelected) {
                setState(() {
                    _isSelected = isSelected;
                    widget.onSelected(isSelected, widget.chipId);
                }); 
            },  
            selectedColor: Color(0xffeadffd),
        );  
    }
}
```

Now some of the filterChips are checked by default as expected but the filterChips don't work anymore.
When I try to check or uncheck them nothing happens, the filterChips stay in their initial state.
What's wrong with my code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer:

```
class filterChipWidget extends StatefulWidget {
    final String chipName;
    final int chipId;
    final bool isChecked;
    Function(bool, int) onSelected;

    filterChipWidget({Key? key, required this.chipName, required this.chipId, required this.isChecked, required this.onSelected}) : super(key: key);

    @override
    _filterChipWidgetState createState() => _filterChipWidgetState();
}

class _filterChipWidgetState extends State<filterChipWidget> {
    var _isSelected; // <= Set this variable to null by default.

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        // The variable is now set to the isChecked property value during the widget instantiation.
        // Then it will be set to the isSelected value in the setState() function.      
        _isSelected = _isSelected ?? widget.isChecked; 

        return FilterChip(
            label: Text(widget.chipName),
            labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Color(0xff6200ee),fontSize: 16.0,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            selected: _isSelected,
            shape:RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                  30.0),),
            backgroundColor: Color(0xffededed),
            onSelected: (isSelected) {
                setState(() {
                    _isSelected = isSelected;
                    widget.onSelected(isSelected, widget.chipId);
                }); 
            },  
            selectedColor: Color(0xffeadffd),
        );  
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.